# Initial Value with Form not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form with an initial value, but I can't get the initial value to show.

```
def addaward(request):  
  if request.method == "POST":
      form = AwardForm(request.POST) 
      form.save()    


  else: 
    form = AwardForm(initial={'title': 'hi!'})
  return render_to_response('award.html',{'form': AwardForm}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

What is really strange is when I delete the line with

```
  form = AwardForm(initial={'title': 'hi!'})
```

the form still shows with no error messages.

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from students.models import Student

class AwardForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
        model = Award
```

**Models.py**

```
class Award(models.Model)
   date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, editable = True)
   student = models.ForeignKey('Student')
   type = models.CharField('Category', max_length = 30)
   title = models.CharField('Title of Award', max_length = 30)
   description = models.TextField('Description')
```

Any ideas would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the Award model rather than the student model.  If that was just a typo then the problem is probably that your model has not field named title.  Did you mean name?

Comment: Opps. Yea of course. I inserted the wrong model onto SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this:

```
{'form': AwardForm}
```

should be:

```
{'form': form }
```